# Add Second Colorbar to a Seaborn Heatmap / Clustermap

Tags: python, python-3.x, heatmap, seaborn, colorbar

I was trying to help someone add a colorbar for the **vertical** blue bar in the image below. We tried many variations of `plt.colorbar(row_colors)` (like above and below `sns.clustermap()`) and looked around online for 2 hours, but no luck. We just want to add a colorbar for the blues, please help!

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

feat_mat, freq, label = pickle.load(open('file.pkl', 'rb'))

feat_mat_df = pd.DataFrame(feat_mat[4])

freq_df = pd.DataFrame(freq)
freq_df_transposed = freq_df.transpose()

my_palette = dict(zip(set(freq_df_transposed[int('4')]), sns.color_palette("PuBu", len(set(freq_df_transposed[int('4')]))))))
row_colors = freq_df_transposed[int('4')].map(my_palette)

sns.clustermap(feat_mat_df, metric="euclidean", standard_scale=1, method="complete", cmap="coolwarm", row_colors = row_colors)

plt.show()
```

[image]

This is where he based his code from: [#405 Dendrogram with heatmap and coloured leaves](https://python-graph-gallery.com/405-dendrogram-with-heatmap-and-coloured-leaves/)

Comment: did my answer solve this issue? or are there other problems with clustermap specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work for your purposes- I didn't have a clustermap example available but the logic is the same to do what you want to do. Basically-you're going to take that list of colors you made and imshow it, then hide the imshow plot, and plot the colorbar in its place. 
In my example, I use make_axes_locatable to place axes next to the plot with your data to put the colorbar inside - [https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M43Fd.png).  I find placing a new axes for other objects (legends color maps or otherwise) easier than trying to draw them on the same axes.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import random


uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (5,5))
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

axDivY = divider.append_axes( 'right', size=0.2, pad= 0.1)
axDivY2 = divider.append_axes( 'right', size=0.2, pad= 0.2)

# we will use this for the colorscale bar
axDivY3 = divider.append_axes( 'right', size=0.2, pad= 0.2)
ax1 = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax, cbar_ax=axDivY)


# the palette you were using to make the label column on the clustermap

# some simulated labels for your data with values
color_label_list =[random.randint(0,20) for i in range(20)]

pal =  sns.color_palette("PuBu", len(set(color_label_list)))
n = len(pal)
size = 1

# plot the colors with imshow to make a colormap later
ax2 = axDivY2.imshow(np.array([color_label_list]),
              cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(list(pal)),
              interpolation="nearest", aspect="auto")
# turn off the axes so they aren't visible- note that you need ax.axis('off) if you have older matplotlib
axDivY2.set_axis_off()
axDivY2.set_visible(False)
# plot the colorbar on the other axes (which is on top of the one that we turned off)
plt.colorbar(ax2, cax = axDivY3) ;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is where he based his code from: https://python-graph-gallery.com/405-dendrogram-with-heatmap-and-coloured-leaves/